# Three consecutive positive integers divisible by $3$, $5$ and $7$ respectively

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find three consecutive positive integer that are divisible by $3$, $5$, and $7$ respectively. Answer should be with or without proof but the result submitted should be with proper method.

Comment: Do you want explicit numbers or a proof such numbers exist? The Chinese Remainder Theorem will be useful in both cases.

Comment: i want three consecutive positive number which are divisible by 3,5,7 respectively . Means three distinct consecutive numbers divisible by 3,5,7 respectively.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is this "proper method" you speak of? I just went for a walk around the block, when all of a sudden a booming voice said "Fifty four! Fifty five! Fifty six! These are the numbers he seeks!"

So here they are. The method of acquiring them is "divine revelation". Is this a proper method?

Comment: The wording of the question looks like some contest problem. Or am I just too suspecting?

Comment: i dont know the chinese remainder theorem

Comment: @PeterKošinár My intuition was "homework", so I guess I am even more suspecting than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the required integers be $n, n + 1, n + 2$. Then, we have, from the divisibility conditions :

$$\begin{align}n &= 3a \\&= -1 + 5b \\&= -2 + 7c\end{align}$$

Now consider $3a = -1 + 5b$. From this we have:

$$\begin{align}3a &\equiv -1 \mod 5 \\
9a &\equiv -3 \mod 5\\
-a &\equiv -3 \mod 5
\\a &\equiv 3 \mod 5\end{align}$$

so we deduce $a = 3 + 5m$ for integer $m$. Then, $n = 9 + 15m$. Moving on, we look at $n = 9 + 15m = -2 + 7c$:

$$\begin{align}
9 + 15m &\equiv -2 \mod 7\\
m &\equiv -11 \mod 7\\
m &\equiv 3 \mod 7
\end{align}$$

so we deduce that $m = 3 + 7k$ for integer $k$. Then,
$$\begin{align}n &= 9 + 15m \\&= 9 + 15(3 + 7k) \\&= 54 + 105k\end{align}$$

So we conclude that required integers are $54 + 105k, 55 + 105k, 56 + 105k$ for integer $k$. $159, 160, 161$ is an example.

The whole of the above is, in essence, what we call the "Chinese Remainder Theorem".

Comment: one more possible answer is 54 ;55;56.

Comment: Indeed : It will work for any integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

This translates to looking for an $x$ such that:
\begin{align}
x     &\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
x + 1 &\equiv 0 \pmod{5} \\
x + 2 &\equiv 0 \pmod{7}
\end{align}
This is:
\begin{align}
x &\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
x &\equiv 4 \pmod{5} \\
x &\equiv 5 \pmod{7}
\end{align}
Solutions to such systems of congruences are the matter of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\,3\mid x-\color{#c00}1,\ \ 5\mid x,\ \ 7\mid x+\color{#0a0}1.\ $ Therefore $\,x = 5i\,$  for some integer $\,i.$

${\rm mod}\ 7\!:\ {-\color{#0a0}1}\equiv x\equiv 5i\,$ so $\,i\equiv -1/5\equiv -8/(-2)\equiv 4\,$ so $\ x = 5i = 5(4\!+\!7j) = 20\!+\!35j.$

${\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ \ \  \color{#c00}1\equiv x\equiv 20\!+\!35j\equiv 2-j,\ $ so $\ j = 1\!+\!3k,\,$ so $\ x = 20\!+\!35(1\!+\!3k)=55\!+\!105k$

**Remark** $\ $ In the same way one can prove that for any odd integer $\,n\ $ (above $\,n=5)$

$$ n\!-\!2\mid x-1,\,\ n\mid x,\,\ n+2\mid x+1\iff x \equiv \dfrac{n^3-3n}2\!\! \pmod{n^3-4n}$$